# Upload Files to Google Drive using Google Drive API in ASP.Net with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-drive-api, google-oauth

Upload Files to Google Drive using Google Drive API in ASP.Net with C#.
Initially I have completed all the steps that needs to create the API with google and get Client ID and Client Secret.
And then used this code.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    con = new SqlConnection(connStr);
    cm = new ClassMain();
    cmd = new SqlCommand();
    google();
}
protected void UploadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["File"] = FileUpload1.PostedFile;
    GoogleConnect.Authorize("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file");

}
protected void google()
{
    GoogleConnect.ClientId = "<Client ID>";
    GoogleConnect.ClientSecret = "<Client Secret>";
    GoogleConnect.RedirectUri = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Split('?')[0];
    GoogleConnect.API = EnumAPI.Drive;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["code"]))
    {
        string code = Request.QueryString["code"];
        string json = GoogleConnect.PostFile(code, (HttpPostedFile)Session["File"], "");
        GoogleDriveFile file = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Deserialize<GoogleDriveFile>(json);           
    }
    if (Request.QueryString["error"] == "access_denied")
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Access denied.')", true);
    }
}
```

It will work properly for small size of file like 1 to 10 MB, If File size Increase then give error-

The webpage at http://localhost:1762/ChangeADCUploadedNewded/BlankPage.aspx?code=4%2fAk03HmpOQsV5Na_pM2fs5vzdfJTa2yoMzWAy-lD_CVE might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

resolve the error.

403-Invalid Credential error is not come at this time.

Comment: Sir I fill right client id and secret and It should work for some time then give error but in question I change some of keywords in this ID, If you won't the correct then I'll give you sir.

Comment: are you sure you are using Googles Client library?

Comment: Which NuGet package did you import?

Comment: using ASPSnippets.GoogleAPI;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization; with .Net Entity Frame Work 3.5

Comment: That's not the Google .net client library this is https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Drive.v2/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87456/discussion-between-abhishek-and-daimto).

Comment: sorry I have a meeting in 5 minutes this might help:  http://www.daimto.com/google-drive-api-c-upload/  Unless you want to continue using that 3rd party script

Answer (score 0):

I did a little research and found that Google used to have the 10MB limit for uploads as you can see here: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/N9Ruvnf0Jx8 but they increased that limit last year to 1TB. The only limitation that I was able to find for files larger than 10MB is when the uploaded file needs to be converted to a Google Doc, Sheet or Slides.